# Printing posters via tiled regular paper sizes on macOS?

Tags: printing, macos

I find myself often needing to print posters.  I'd like to use an app like Pages to generate the poster layout initially and then just print it, but obviously there's no print engine in macOS that splits things up in such a fashion.

Is there a preferred method to take some output file (such as a PDF) and then will split it up for assembly?